# Laravel set value in get route

Tags: php, laravel

I have one route which is accepting one argument perfectly as

```
  Route::get('view-request/type/{type}/id/{id}', 'CustomerReqController@testing')->name('request.manage');
```

and also call it in blade by this

```
<a href="{{route('request.manage',['type'=>'new','id'=>'data'])}}"
```

and the controller is

```
public function testing(Request $request,$type,$id){
    dd($request->all());
}
```

it gives me error

> Missing required parameters for [Route: request.manage] [URI: admin/view-request/type/{type}/id/{id}]. (View: /var/www/html/ehs_crm_laravel/resources/views/common/navbar.blade.php) (View: /var/www/html/ehs_crm_laravel/resources/views/common/navbar.blade.php) (View: /var/www/html/ehs_crm_laravel/resources/views/common/navbar.blade.php)

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: The second argument to `route()` should be an _array_ with the values.

Comment: but when i made  Route::get('delete-tagservicetolocation/{loc_id}/{ser_id}', 'LocationController@DeleteTagServicesToLocation')->name('tagservicetolocation.delete'); and it was working on this route

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-route, https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/urls#urls-for-named-routes

Comment: @MagnusEriksson edited according but not working

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the above HTML is where that error actually occurs and that you're not calling `route('request.manage', ...)` from somewhere else as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use:

```
<a href="{{ route('request.manage', ['type' => 'new', 'id' => 'data']) }}">
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get your route parameter by simply using this code.  hope this will work for you. for Get and Post method both.

```
public function testing(Request $request)
{
    $type= $request->type;
    $id= $request->id;

}
```

Comment: what is then in blade is it the same or i have to edit it?

Comment: you can set this variables according to you by just passing in second parameter of view method.

view('view', ['id'=>$id,'type'=>$type]);

Comment: The question isn't how to get the URL params. It's how to create a url from a named route using the `route()`-helper. Also, does the `$request` object really contain the passed route parameters? We're not talking about GET or POST params.

Answer (score 1):

follow steps this code is working to me.

1 : declare route

```
Route::get('view-request/type/{type}/id/{id}', 'UserController@index')->name('request.manage');
```

2: create link

```
<a href="{{ route('request.manage', ['type'=>'test','id'=>6]) }}">Register</a>
```

3: get data in controller

```
public function index($type,$id,Request $request){
        echo $type;
        echo $id;

    }
```